# Particle horizon and big bang

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, big-bang, cosmic-microwave-background

The farthest radiation we can see is from the particle horizon. But the farthest radiation is the CMB. Why does all radiation from the particle horizon stem from that earliest possible source time? In other words, why is the CMB almost infinitely redshifted, suggesting that if we could see right back to the BB, the light would be infinitely redshifted? Infinite redshift is a feature of any light coming from the particle horizon, so for some reason the BB is the only event on the particle horizon.

Answer (score 4):

> The farthest radiation we can see is from the particle horizon.

Not quite right. It is quite hard to see light through a plasma. Note that we can see the surface of the sun, but it is hard to see the inside (and not just because the light from the center takes so long to get out from repeated scattering, it also just is hard to image because it scattered so much). So what you see (with electromagnetic waves) is different than the particle horizon.

The particle horizon extends out farther. It limits neutrinos and gravity waves and everything. Electromagnetic waves stop at the surface of last scattering not because that is the big bang but merely for the reason that long ago the universe was quite hot and dense and so there were enough ions to make it hard to see past it.

The CMR comes from the surface of last scattering from the epoch of recombination. The light was scattering off ions up until it started to get cool enough and undense enough that there was a chance that light can escape and travel to us without getting scattered over and over again.

> But the farthest radiation is the CMB.

There is radiation farther away. Just like there is radiation inside the sun even though we can't see it because we only see the surface. Think of it as being hard to see hot things and the universe used to be hot everywhere as opposed to now where it is only hot in some places.

> Why does all radiation from the particle horizon stem from that earliest possible source time?

It doesn't. If we can detect gravitational waves we will be able to see things from before recombination we will see things older than CMR. And neutrinos are also detectable from before recombination, recombination is just about electromagnetic ions interacting with photons.

Comment: I'm sorry my question was not clear enough. I know everything you say, what I'm asking is why does the particle horizon appear to be at the initial singularity? Or, equivalently, why is the light we see from as close as possible to the horizon also the light we see from the earliest possible time? This seems a strange coincidence, and Leonard Susskind, in a reply to this question I sent him, said it is called 'the cosmic coincidence' and has not been explained. He said some people are working on it. (continued below)

Comment: By earliest possible time, I mean the earliest possible time we can see light from, i.e., the surface of last scattering. It wd seem possible that (if this coincidence did not hold) the farthest radiation we cd see comes from as near as it can be to the horizon, but set out at some later date than the surface of last scattering, and then we wd not be able to see that surface because it is behind the horizon. We'd just be seeing light from some later source just in front of the horizon.

Comment: @murraydenofsky I don't understand your concern at all. If you look out at a particular time in all directions you see things close things can block farther things and farther away things can be things from when the universe was oldest. The surface of last scattering is not anywhere near the particle horizon. The particle horizon is increasing in time so we currently see bigger sections of the CMR than the earth could have seen millions of years ago. You say it is possible some that the particle horizon could have stopped before we reached the surface of last scattering, ...

Comment: But that isn't how the particle horizon is defined, it is defined to include everything we can see. So there isn't a policeman telling us the surface of last scattering is off limits. Now if the universe had been cold back then or if we used something other than light then we can see farther. I don't see how you make a coincidence about the fact that you have a personal preference for microwave and photon astronomy rather than neutrino astronomy. The universe doesn't know or care which kind of astronomy you prefer so that doesn't seem like a coincidence of any kind. Isn't the CMR a red herring

Comment: No, I'm not preferring photons. In my 2nd sentence, I said the particle horizon appears likely to be at or very close to the initial sg., since the CMB is so close to 0 frequency, and is also very close in emission time (100K yrs.) to the sg. It's a good guess that the horizon, therefore, is at the singularity. If that is so, using neutrinos, we'd be able to see as close as we wish to the singularity, but not the singularity itself, which is at the horizon. My query was why shd the horizon be exactly at the singularity. Susskind seemed to say this is a mystery, the 'cosmic coincidence'.